# Show Json in same cshtml page using ajax after post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a `Search` function, I'm returning a `Json` result from the Controller Action method. Everything is working fine, except that I want to show the results from the Action Method in the same Index page(my default page: `http://localhost:51450/`), but for some reason it routes to `http://localhost:51450/Students/SearchStudent` and in that page it just shows the result in json format: `[{"StudentID":166,"Name":"ss","LastName":"s","Age":23}]` and of course there is not any format in there. I'm using ajax with the purpose to show the results in the same Index page.. There should be something that I'm missing, what is it?

Controller Action Methods(1 just to show the view and the other to submit the filled form...):

```
public PartialViewResult SearchStudent()
{            
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult SearchStudent(string name)
{
    List<Student> list = db.Students.Where(s => s.Name == name).ToList();            
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Partial View(The user should put a name and in then click submit):

```
@model Pedro2.Models.Student
using (@Html.BeginForm("SearchStudent", "Students", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formSearchStudent" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitSearch" data-url="@Url.Action("SearchStudent", "Students")" />
    </div>
}
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Index view(only the part concerning to this operation):

```
<p class="hand" id="pSearch" data-urlSearch="@Url.Action("SearchStudent","Students")"> Search by name</p>
<div id="ShowFormSearch"></div>
```

And the JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#pSearch").click(function () {
        ShowSearchPage();
        return false;
    })

    $("#submitSearch").click(function () {
        SearchStudent();
        return false;
    })
})

function SearchStudent() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: $("#submitSearch").data('url'),
        data: $("#formSearchStudent").serialize + { name: $("#Name").val() },
        datatype : 'json'
    }).success(function (result) {            
        $("#divResult").html(result)
    }).error(function () {
        $("#divResult").html("An error occurred")
    })
}

function ShowSearchPage()
{  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: $("#pSearch").data('urlsearch')    
    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html(result)
    }).error(function () {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html("An error occurred")
    })
}
```

If you need to ask me anything just let me know

Comment: The JQuery code is on `Partial VIew` or `Index` page?

Comment: @user55 The JQuery code is separated from the Views, I'm using a separated .js file and inside there I put all my JQuery code, I put a reference to that file on BundleConfig and a reference to that ScriptBundle from my _Layout page so it has access to all the views

Comment: The other thing is you are using `Form`, on `Form submit` it is redirecting to 'Students/SearchStudent'. If you want to update some little part of the view through `Ajax` and want to remain on same view then don't use form tag..

Comment: If your redirecting, it means your making a normal submit and the script is not working. Change the button to `type="button"` and debug your script

Comment: And it just needs to be `data: $("#formSearchStudent").serialize(),` (no need to add the `name` value twice)

Comment: Also, why is it `type: 'get'` when you clearly want to go to the POST method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is working now, I fixed the code according to what you suggested and it's working properly now, I think that the big issue was that I was using an `<input type="submit">` instead of `<input type="button">` inside the form of the Partial View and then once pressed the button the script wasn't executing, the other thing is that I changed the function because the partial view doesn't appear when the DOM was ready, it appears after when an user click on a link, so I need to use `$(document).on("click", "#submitSearch", function (e) {})` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: This is the function with the changes:                       `$(document).on("click", "#submitSearch", function (e) {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $("#submitSearch").data('url'),
            data: $("#formSearchStudent").serialize(),
            datatype : 'json'
        }).success(function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, res) {                
                var paragraph = "<p>" + res.Name + "</p>"
                $("#divResult").append(paragraph)
            })            
        })`

Comment: `.error(function () {
            $("#divResult").html("An error occurred")
        })
        return false;
})`                                                                                                          If you want you can put an answer so I can give you the point, thanks